# matching regular expression for normalization

Tags: regex

really bad with regular expression, so seeking help here
the function i m writing is to accept an input, and return the normalized output
so input must match certain, instead of listing all possible combination, is there someways to use RegExp?

e.g. jackjill | jack jill | jack-jill | jack&jill | jack & jill | jack-&-jill | jack and jill | jackandjill | jack-and-jill | jack n jill |..., the function will return 'Jack & Jill'

so input.match(/jack[ -&n]*jill/) covers the space, -, n, but how about the 'and'?

Comment: Try this `jack.*?jill`

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the pattern using optional character classes and an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) using `|`

```
\bjack(?:[ &-]+|[ -]?(?:and|n)[ -]?)?jill\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WhjKCo/1)

If what is before and after the `n` or `and` should be the same, you can use a capturing group for the part before and use a backreference to match the same content after it.

```
\bjack(?:[ &-]+|([ -]?)(?:and|n)\1)?jill\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\bjack` Word boundary, then match jack
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[ &-]+` Match either a space, `&` or `-`
  - `|` Or
  - `([ -]?)` Optionally match a space or `-` in capture **group 1**
  - `(?:and|n)` Match either `and` or `n`
  - `\1` Backreference to what is captured in group 1
- `)?` Close group and make ik optional
- `jill\b` Match `jill` followed by a word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EqpHGi/1)

Answer (score 0):

You could replace `jack[ -&n]*jill` by `\bjack.*?jill\b`.

**Details**:

- `.*?`: any letter between jack and jill
- `\b`: word boundary

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3GtpQE/2)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
replace(/\b(jack)[\s&-]*(?:(?:n|and)[\s&-]*)?(jill)\b/gi, '$1 & $2')
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/E02Ziz/1/).

***Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    jack                     'jack'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [\s&-]*                  any character of: whitespace (\n, \r, \t,
                           \f, and " "), '&', '-' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      n                        'n'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      and                      'and'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\s&-]*                  any character of: whitespace (\n, \r,
                             \t, \f, and " "), '&', '-' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    jill                     'jill'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```

JavaScript:

```js
const text = " jackjill | jack jill | jack-jill | jack&jill | jack & jill | jack-&-jill | jack and jill | jackandjill | jack-and-jill | jack n jill jack knows Jill";
console.log(text.replace(/\b(jack)[\s&-]*(?:(?:n|and)[\s&-]*)?(jill)\b/gi, '$1 & $2'));
```